# new command not working properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, diagrams, pstricks

Hi I am trying to create a pie chart and have used the following code to do so. I import everything properly, however, I cannot use my created "data" command for some reason. I get the error "Undefined Control Sequence". What am I doing wrong:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[landscape, a4paper, bottom=0cm, margin=0in, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}


%Header Stuff
\newpagestyle{myheader}{%
\sethead{}{\sffamily\large\raisebox{6ex}{\parbox{2cm}{
    \hspace*{10cm}
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{images/toptrack_logo.png}
}}}{}
}

%Customization
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot
\usepgfplotslibrary{
  units, % Allows to enter the units nicely
  groupplots
}

%Piechart
\degrees[100]
\newcounter{counter}
\SpecialCoor
\newcommand\data[2][gray]{%
    \pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#1,opacity=.5](0,0){4}{!\thecounter}{!\thecounter\space #2 add}%
    \uput{2}[!#2 2 div \thecounter\space add](0,0){#2\%}%
    \addtocounter{counter}{#2}%
}


\newcommand{\tabitem}{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\definecolor{customgrey}{RGB}{78,74,68}
\definecolor{customblue}{RGB}{70,179,211}
\definecolor{customblack1}{RGB}{35,31,32}
\definecolor{customblack2}{RGB}{64,64,66}
\definecolor{customdarkblue}{RGB}{79,129,189}
\definecolor{customlightblue}{RGB}{142,174,213}
\definecolor{customdarkred}{RGB}{192,80,77}
\definecolor{customlightred}{RGB}{217,147,145}



\title{test}
\author{sinasohi}
\date{January 2017}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\include{Page0}
\pagestyle{myheader}{
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtPageLowerLeft{
    \hspace{-0.25cm}
    \includegraphics[width=30cm]{images/toptrack_footer.png}
 }}{
\include{Page1}
\include{Page2}
\include{Page3}
\include{Page4}
\include{Page5}
}}

\end{document}
```

Where I "use" my piechart in a Page3:

```
\hspace{2cm}{\Huge \color{customblack1} ABCD inddeling}

\begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-4.5)(4.5,4.5)
    \data[red]{10}
    \data[orange]{40}
    \data[yellow]{30}
    \data[blue]{20}
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: Nobody but you can reproduce your issue as your code is useless to us. We will just get unrelated errors. In any case, please give the exact text of the error. It will have told you *which* control sequence is undefined, which should help you to diagnose the problem. That said, you cannot `\include` something into a page style like that. `\include` always starts a new page, so it can't go into the background of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a macro for pie charts:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psChart[userColor={red!30,green!30,blue!40,gray,cyan!50,
    magenta!60,cyan},chartSep=30pt,shadow=true,shadowsize=5pt
]{34.5,17.2,20.7,15.5,5.2,6.9}{6}{2}
\psset{nodesepA=5pt,nodesepB=-10pt}
\ncline{psChartO1}{psChart1}\nput{0}{psChartO1}{1000 (34.5\%)}
\ncline{psChartO2}{psChart2}\nput{150}{psChartO2}{500 (17.2\%)}
\ncline{psChartO3}{psChart3}\nput{-90}{psChartO3}{600 (20.7\%)}
\ncline{psChartO4}{psChart4}\nput{0}{psChartO4}{450 (15.5\%)}
\ncline{psChartO5}{psChart5}\nput{0}{psChartO5}{150 (5.2\%)}
\ncline{psChartO6}{psChart6}\nput{0}{psChartO6}{200 (6.9\%)}
\bfseries
\rput(psChartI1){Taxes}\rput(psChartI2){Rent}\rput(psChartI3){Bills}
\rput(psChartI4){Car}\rput(psChartI5){Gas}\rput(psChartI6){Food}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this in sharelatex and I still get the same error i posted: https://gyazo.com/9a63dc913319000285d8da626aceb058

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6257e9acd894121244701c6595aa8f1d

Comment: https://gyazo.com/77f920f4ade00017726033ba435181e3

Comment: https://gyazo.com/bee54676d590f18be8b774ed155bb978

Comment: You have to run it with `xelatex` or the sequence `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: Thank you very much. That's where the misudnerstand had occured on my end!!